# Hadoop multinode cluster too slow. How do I increase speed of data processing?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have a 6 node cluster - 5 DN and 1 NN. All have 32 GB RAM. All slaves have 8.7 TB HDD. DN has 1.1 TB HDD. Here is the link to my [core-site.xml](https://pastebin.com/qnF79dgN) , [hdfs-site.xml](https://pastebin.com/TazMQdJK) , [yarn-site.xml](https://pastebin.com/fZz7fy0r).

After running an MR job, i checked my RAM Usage which is mentioned below:

Namenode

```
free -g
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      31           7          15           0           8          22
Swap:     31           0          31
```

Datanode :

Slave1 :

```
free -g
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      31           6           6           0          18          24
Swap:     31           3          28
```

Slave2:

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      31           2           4           0          24          28
Swap:     31           1          30
```

Likewise, other slaves have similar RAM usage. Even if a single job is submitted, the other submitted jobs enter into `ACCEPTED` state and wait for the first job to finish and then they start.

Here is the output of `ps` command of the **JAR** that I submnitted to execute the MR job:

```
/opt/jdk1.8.0_77//bin/java -Dproc_jar -Xmx1000m 
-Dhadoop.log.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop/logs -Dyarn.log.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop/logs 
-Dhadoop.log.file=yarn.log -Dyarn.log.file=yarn.log 
-Dyarn.home.dir= -Dyarn.id.str= -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console 
-Dyarn.root.logger=INFO,console -Dyarn.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml 
-Dhadoop.log.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop/logs -Dyarn.log.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop/logs 
-Dhadoop.log.file=yarn.log -Dyarn.log.file=yarn.log 
-Dyarn.home.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop -Dhadoop.home.dir=/home/hduser/hadoop 
-Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Dyarn.root.logger=INFO,console 
-classpath --classpath of jars
 org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar abc.jar abc.mydriver2 /raw_data /mr_output/02
```

Is there any settings that I can change/add to allow multiple jobs to run simultaneously and speed up current data processing ? I am using hadoop 2.5.2. The cluster is in PROD environment and I can not take it down for updating hadoop version.

EDIT 1 : I started a new MR job with 362 GB of data and still the RAM usage is around 8 GB and 22 GB of RAM is free. Here is my job submission command -

```
nohup yarn jar abc.jar def.mydriver1 /raw_data /mr_output/01 &
```

Here is some more information :

```
18/11/22 14:09:07 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 130363
18/11/22 14:09:10 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:130372
```

Is there some additional memory parameters that we can use to submit the job to have efficient memory usage ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can edit the **mapred-default.xml**

The Params you are looking for are

- mapreduce.job.running.map.limit
- mapreduce.job.running.reduce.limit

0 (Probably what it is set too at the moment) means UNLIMITED.

Looking at your Memory 32G/Machine seems too small.

What CPU/Cores are you having ? I would expect Quad CPU/16 Cores Minimum. Per Machine.

Comment: I do not have a **mapred-default.xml** in `$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/`. If my memory is too small per machine, then why does the `free` command shows a lot of free memory ?   Here is the CPU used on each machine - Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40GHz and `nproc` commands gives me `24` cores per machine.

Comment: How long do you MapReduce jobs take ? 

I was running 30 DN's each with 128 Gb of memory  - and we dropped MapReduce for Spark/HBase due to speed.

Have you tried using Hive ? Are the results the Same ?? Pheonix (from Hortonworks) was also good.

Comment: Yes, I am using hive 1.2.1 stable. After submitting a long query I get similar output - 
    Launching Job 7 out of 21
    Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
    In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
    set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
    In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
    set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
    In order to set a constant number of reducers:
    set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
    Hadoop job information for Stage-14: number of mappers: 380; number of reducers: 487

Comment: I have an estimation of MR job based on input data size - 300GB of input data takes around 24 hours to process. And `free` command shows similar memory consumption even when hive queries with above mentioned mapper and reducer numbers are running.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `yarn-site.xml` your `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` setting of 10240 is too high.  This effectively means you only have at best 18 vcores available.  This might be the right setting for a cluster where you have tons of memory but for 32GB it's way too large.  Drop it to 1 or 2GB.

Remember, HDFS block sizes are what each mapper typically consumes.  So 1-2GB of memory for 128MB of data sounds more reasonable.  The added benefit is you could have up to 180 vcores available which will process jobs 10x faster than 18 vcores.

Comment: Do I need to restart the cluster everytime I make changes in the yarn config files ? or just the changes in XML file will make my next job run with the new value of `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb` ? I have made it 1 GB which sounds reasonable. I am yet to execute the job with new settings.  I will let you know how this fares out. Thank you for your time !

Comment: I started a new MR job with 362 GB of data and still the RAM usage is around 8 GB and 22 GB of RAM is free. Here is my job submission command - `nohup yarn jar abc.jar def.mydriver1 /raw_data /mr_output/01 &` . Here is some more information - `18/11/22 14:09:07 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 130363
18/11/22 14:09:10 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:130372
` Is there some additional memory parameters that we can use to submit the job to have efficient memory usage ?

Comment: You need to restart all the YARN services when you change the `yarn-site.xml`.  You should look at the YARN UI (RM_URL/cluster/apps) to see what your usage is.  There are probably more settings you need to tune.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea of how a 4 node 32 core 128GB RAM per node cluster is setup:

For Tez: Divide RAM/CORES = Max TEZ Container size
So in my case: **128/32** **= 4GB**

**TEZ:**
[image]

---

**YARN:**

[image]