# Tuning Hadoop parameters

Tags: hadoop

Is there a way to fine tune Hadoop configuration parameters without having to run tests for every possible combination?
I am currently working on an 8 nodes cluster and I want to optimize the performances of map reduce task as well as spark performance (running on top of hdfs).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO. You need to play around and run smoke tests to determine optimal performance for your cluster. So I would start by checking out these

Links:

- https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/103176/hdfs-settings-for-better-hadoop-performance.html
- http://crazyadmins.com/tune-hadoop-cluster-to-get-maximum-performance-part-1/
- http://crazyadmins.com/tune-hadoop-cluster-to-get-maximum-performance-part-2/

Some topics discussed that will effect MapReduce jobs:

- Configure HDFS block size for optimal performance
- Avoid file sizes that are smaller than a block size
- Tune DataNode JVM for optimal performance
- Enable HDFS short circuit reads
- Avoid reads or write from stale DataNodes

---

To give you an idea of how a 4 node 32 core 128GB RAM per node cluster is set up in YARN/TEZ: (From [Hadoop multinode cluster too slow. How do I increase speed of data processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53406172/hadoop-multinode-cluster-too-slow-how-do-i-increase-speed-of-data-processing/53836656#53836656))

For Tez: Divide RAM/CORES = Max TEZ Container size
So in my case: **128/32** **= 4GB**

**TEZ:**
[image]

---

**YARN:**

I like to run max RAM I can spare per node with YARN, mine is a little higher than recommendations, but the recommended values cause crashes in TEZ/MR jobs so 76GB works better my case. You need to play with all these values!

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we automate this operation, similarly to cross-validation in python?

Comment: I would make a bunch of hql scripts/queries that hit the cluster hard, use a stopwatch/timer/process time, record everything and make adjustments